# Create a branch in git using a TeamCity build step

Tags: git, powershell, teamcity

Is it possible to create a branch in git via a TeamCity build step? I've tried running a command line build step and creating batch files/powershell scripts/etc and can't seem to figure out.

Basically, Just want to do this

```
call git checkout master
call git pull origin master
call git branch %BRANCH_NAME%
call git checkout %BRANCH_NAME%
call git push origin %BRANCH_NAME%
call git checkout master
```

Comment: Well, you don't describe what your problem is, so getting a solution will be tough.

Comment: It looks like you've got it.  What about your solution doesn't work?